# Epsilon delta study material

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, epsilon-delta

I want to practice epsilon-delta method for problems in analysis. Does anyone have any suggestions for books with solutions, or solution books available, for undergraduate analysis?

Edit: I didn't write book because I cant buy books. Was referring to free material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of problem books available as in the comment but neverthless try this book:

> M.H.Protter and C.B. Morrey: A First Course in
>   Real Analysis

The explanation of $\epsilon$-$\delta$ continuity in this book is exactly what you want!(Read Section $2.1$ with exercises. In this section, the author explains how to find a $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon$ and give lot of problems for practice )

Comment: I can't find free pdf of it.

Comment: Give your email id, i will send it!

Comment: suyashsingh234@gmail.com thanks

Comment: I sent it ...Check your mail!